# Any Cheap Type C to USB Converter?

Tags: usb, macbook

I've recently purchased the Macbook M1, There are only two types c ports available. I am thinking to purchase the Apple USB hub, but it is very expensive.

Can you suggest to me some cheaper options?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, those do exist. USB-C is just USB-A with some extra features and a smaller connector. A passive adapter will be enough, like this one: https://www.amazon.nl/USB-adapter-compatibel-telefoon-apparaat/dp/B08R8NDQ98/

Answer (score 0):

The MacBook M1 models don't just have USB-C, but support Thunderbolt too.
If you want to use the full potential of the ports, search for that instead.

Something likes this looks reasonable for the price point:
[https://www.amazon.com/Multiport-Adapter-Ethernet-Thunderbolt-MacBook/dp/B097R7B472/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B097R7B472)

Comment: Thanks, Mate. Also Any Suggestions for a good external monitor for M1?

Comment: That would be for a different question. You can use the "Ask Question" button on the top right of the page for that.